# Can't get user input to apply an update

Tags: javascript, html, class, mongoose, input

Everything seems to be working in my code, except on my update I'm trying to get the user inputted text from my HTML page and apply it as an update, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Here's my javascript:

```
app.patch("/tm/v1/tasks/:id", async (req,res)=>{
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const update = { name: String(document.getElementsByClassName('task-edit-name'))}
    const taskUpdated = await Task.findOneAndUpdate({id}, update, {new: true});
    res.status(200).json({taskUpdated});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({msg: error});
  };
});
```

Here's my HTML (I'm trying to get the input from this):

```
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="task-edit-name" />
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array and you're not getting the `value` from the element. Also, `document` doesn't exist on the server. How are you hitting your update endpoint?